# Ruby on rails passenger apache problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did, gem install passenger, passenger-install-apache2-module

http://localhost/

I'm getting this error.

http://pastebin.com/YfrEsv3X

### Update

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.8)
actionpack (3.0.8)
activemodel (3.0.8)
activerecord (3.0.8)
activeresource (3.0.8)
activesupport (3.0.8)
arel (2.1.1, 2.0.10)
bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.0.15)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
devise (1.3.4)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.5.0)
mail (2.3.0, 2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.3.2)
orm_adapter (0.0.5)
passenger (3.0.7)
pg (0.11.0)
polyglot (0.3.1)
postgres-pr (0.6.3)
rack (1.3.0, 1.2.3)
rack-mount (0.8.1, 0.6.14)
rack-test (0.6.0, 0.5.7)
rails (3.0.8)
railties (3.0.8)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rubygems-update (1.8.5)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.27)
warden (1.0.4)
```

Comment: Are you pointing to the correct rvm ruby/gemset with in your Apache/Passenger config?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `bundler` gem as well.

### Update

Now that the OP has posted his gemset...

You must have two gemsets, usually this is because you're using two different rubys.  The `gem` command is just a script, with a shebang line pointing to a Ruby.  The gem list you're showing will be the gemset for that Ruby.  You can see this with this command: `head -1 $(which gem)`

Your passenger configuration must be pointing to a different Ruby with a different gemset.  You can see this in your `passenger.conf` lines for Apache.

Comment: #!/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby

Comment: Right, and which Ruby are you pointing to in your Apache configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect after installing the bundler gem - you may experience other problems if your Gemfile doesn't include all the gems your project requires.
So next time - look at the error message.

```
no such file to load -- bundler
```

from the above example - you can notice that 'bundler' is causing the problem.

That will give you a clue as what other gems you'd need to install and possibly missed out in your Gemfile - in which case issue the command:

```
gem install <missing-gem>
```